# How to view the data document stored in Couchbase lite?

Tags: c#, database, xamarin, couchbase-lite

I am building a xamarin application and I am using couchbase lite as offline database .

How can I view the data saved in couchbase lite ? and where is it stored ?

Comment: @Natrium yes , but I don't find a way to access the data , the tools mentioned didn't work for me

Comment: No, CouchDB ≠ Couchbase. They have a common ancestry but have diverged greatly.

Comment: I found the exact path of the data : "/data/data/com.companyname.couchbasetrial/files/.local/share/Maria" but still I can't find this location or he database files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also query your data. Here is the API documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/csharp.html#query

Answer (score 1):

"How can I view the data" is an extremely broad question. I think the only reasonable answer is to point you to the [Couchbase Lite .NET documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.1/csharp.html), for example the section on [the Document API](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.1/csharp.html#document). If you read the docs and have more specific questions you can ask those.

The exact location of the data in the filesystem depends on the platform you're running on. You can find it in the `DatabaseConfiguration.defaultDirectory` property. But there's almost never a need to use the files directly.

Comment: I found the exact path of the data : "/data/data/com.companyname.couchbasetrial/files/.local/share/Maria" but still I can't find this location or he database files